# Insert Values to SQL from VBA

Tags: sql, vba

I need to insert a Values to the table in SQL Server from VBA .I tried Something I mentioned below .But I couldn't able to achieve my results .please guide me to solve this .I am using Exact Conn String in my Option even though its not functioning.

```
Sub To_SQL()

Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd As ADODB.Command
Dim strSQL As String

'Create a new Connection object
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

'Set the connection string
conn .ConnectionString = "Data Source=55.50.53.9;Initial Catalog=Management;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=licenceusr;Password=******"

'Open the Connection to the database
conn .Open **<ERR Raising
 conn .Execute "insert into MyTableName (firstname, lastname) values('""Dhini""','""Dhini""')"
'Create a new Command object
Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
```

Comment: remove the double quotes around Dhini

Comment: @scaisEdge ,Its not functioing .These through errors in Conn.open line ,